# What's the best way to convert int (1 and 0) to bool (true and false) for model binding of complex type properties?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm integrating some services into my server. But the provider api make some fields use 1 and 0 to indicate bool true and false. So I want to make custom conversion when model binding occurs.

Request sent to my server:

```
{
    ...
    "prefix_success": "1" // or "0"
    ...
}
```

My model:

```cs
public class RequestForm {
    ...

    public bool Success { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the value guaranteed to _always_ be either 1 or 0? If so, you could read the value as a number, and set the value of your bool based on whether the value is greater than 0.

Comment: @JamieTaylor I know, but I don't want to do type conversion inside Api Controller. I prefer to use attributes. But the docs of Offical Custom Model Binding is too complex, I don't know is there simple ways.

Comment: Is it a POST request with JSON payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the simplest. Thank you all.

binder:

```cs
public class IntToBoolModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (int.TryParse(value, out var intValue)) {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(intValue == 0 ? false : true);

        } else if (bool.TryParse(value, out var boolValue)) {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(boolValue);

        } else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(false);

        } else {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, 
                $"{bindingContext.ModelName} should be a int, bool or empty string.");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

usage:

```cs
public class Model {
    ...

    [BindProperty(BinderType = typeof(IntToBoolModelBinder))]
    public bool MarketingConsent { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: this works for me. but i have using the bool inside a collection, but with this solution i could fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/53304214/4999118

Answer (score 2):

If request is a POST with JSON payload, and value is passed as string, then you can do the following:

Create a custom JsonConverter

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace AppNamespace.JsonConverters
{
    public class NumericStringToBooleanConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanRead => true;
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return reader.Value.ToString().Equals("1");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use model attribute JsonConverter

```cs
using AppNamespace.JsonConverters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
--
[JsonProperty("prefix_success")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(NumericStringToBooleanConverter))]
public bool Success { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom model binder for this.

1.Create a `StringToBoolBinder`

```
public class StringToBoolBinder: ComplexTypeModelBinder
{
    IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> _propertyBinders;
    public StringToBoolBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders) : base(propertyBinders)
    {
        _propertyBinders = propertyBinders;
    }
    protected override Task BindProperty(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        string valueFromBody = string.Empty;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            valueFromBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueFromBody))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        if (bindingContext.FieldName == "Success")
        {
            var json = JObject.Parse(valueFromBody);
            string values = Convert.ToString(((JValue)JObject.Parse(valueFromBody)["prefix_success"]).Value);
            if (values == "1")
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(true);
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(false);
            }

        }else
        {
            return base.BindProperty(bindingContext);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }

}
```

2.Create `StringToBoolBinderProvider`

```
public class StringToBoolBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(RequestForm))
        {
            var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
            for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
            {
                var property = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
            }
            return new StringToBoolBinder(propertyBinders);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

3.Register the provider in startup

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                // add custom binder to beginning of collection
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new StringToBoolBinderProvider());
            });
```

4.Action

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] RequestForm form)
```

5.Model

```
public class RequestForm {
   ... 
   public bool Success { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

6.Json Payload

```
{
  ...
  "prefix_success":"1",
  ...
}
```