# ASP.NET Core - ModelBinder - Collection - stuck in endless / infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, binding, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I am facing an issue with custom **ModelBinder** (**IModelBinder** implementation).

This is a model I am trying to bind from query string. The example parameter looks like this:

> ?Where.Name[eq]=Jakub

The class I am trying bind to is this:

```
[MetadataFilterBinder]
public class MetadataFilter
{
    public string Term { get; set; }

    public string Field { get; set; }

    public FilterClause Clause { get; set; }

    // Where.Name[eq]=Jakub
    public static bool TryParse(string s, out MetadataFilter metadataFilter)
    {
        // commented out for brevity
    }
}
```

My attribute annotating this model binder is:

```
public class MetadataFilterBinderAttribute : ModelBinderAttribute
    {
        public MetadataFilterBinderAttribute() : base(typeof(MetadataFilterBinder))
        {
            BindingSource = BindingSource.Query;
        }
    }
```

The ModelBinder implementation:

```
public class MetadataFilterBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

            var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

            var queryStringKeyName = new string(modelName.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());

            var whereKeyValue = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query
                .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key.StartsWith($"{queryStringKeyName}.", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (whereKeyValue.Key == string.Empty)
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(whereKeyValue.Key);
            if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueProviderResult.FirstValue))
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            var result = MetadataFilter.TryParse($"{whereKeyValue.Key}={whereKeyValue.Value}", out var metadataFilter);
            if (result)
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(metadataFilter);
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(modelName, "Invalid metadata filter value.");
            }
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The MetadataFilter class resides in following model that should be bound from QueryString.

```
public class Metadata : IMetadataPaginable, IMetadataSortable, IMetadataFilterable
    {
        public MetadataPaging Paging { get; set; }

        public MetadataSort Sort { get; set; }

        public IReadOnlyCollection<MetadataFilter> Where { get; set; }
    }
```

Now my code and ModelBinder get's executed correctly and all is getting set correctly. I set **ModelBindingResult** & returning **Task.Completed**. However it get stuck in an endless loop that I have no idea how to indicate that it should stop.

The **BindModelAsync** method gets called infinite amount of times until it hits the limit. The **ModelName** keeps incrementing as **"Where[0]"**, **"Where[1]"**, **"Where[2]"**, "Where[n]".

How can I let the Binder know that I am good and that I've bound all the items I needed?

*Note this is not a duplicate of [Inifinite loop during model binding when using [ModelBinder] attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53303414/inifinite-loop-during-model-binding-when-using-modelbinder-attribute)*

Comment: What's this model binding used to?For this query `Where.Name[eq]=Jakub`, how does model property match this query? And you mean this model binding work fine, right? Just the ModelName keeps incrementing?

Comment: @Rena the binding is stuck in endless loop. It matches the query based on the Where and also that's where the custom binder comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting the **ModelBinder** attribute **on the model property**. So my Binder instead of trying to bind each item individually which triggers the endless loop, it binds the whole collection at once and that's when this issue disappears.

Final result:
[image]